# Cubic function with constant K, only given the distance between stationary points

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question: Consider the cubic function :

$y=\frac{x^3}{3} + x^2 + d\cdot x + 10$

where d is a constant, real number. If its stationary points are exactly square root 1332 units apart, find the value of d.

I found the derivative, keeping d in the equation, but when using the distance formula to create an equation for simultaneous equations I was lost. Can anyone help? The question, in theory, should only require knowledge of differential calculus.

Comment: The stationary points correspond to $x$ so that the derivative is zero, or
$$
x^2 + 2x +d = 0
$$
and you indeed can then calculate the distance between the two $x$'s. What did you get when calculating the distance?

Comment: that’s where I got up to but i didn’t know how to incorporate distance

Comment: There are two ways to interpret the question: the abscissas of the stationary points are $\sqrt{1332}$ units apart, of the (Euclidean) distance between these points is $\sqrt{1332}$. Which should we take ?

Comment: the distance between the two points is square root 1332, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

For the stationary points it's first derivative is zero.

So,
$$x^2+2x+d=0$$
$$\implies x=\sqrt{1-d}-1~or,~-\sqrt{1-d}-1$$
When $x=\sqrt{1-d}-1,y=\dfrac{1}{3}\big(2d\sqrt{1-d}-3d-2\sqrt{1-d}+32)$

And when $x=-\sqrt{1-d}-1,y=\dfrac{1}{3}\big(-2d\sqrt{1-d}-3d+2\sqrt{1-d}+32\big)$

Now if you take the distance between these two points and after equalling it with $\sqrt{1332}$,after some simplification you will find-
$$4(1-d)+\dfrac{16}{9}(1-d)^3=1332$$
$$Let, 1-d=p$$
$$\implies \dfrac{16}{9}p^3+4p-1332=0$$
$$p=9[only~real~root]$$
$$Hence,~~d=-8$$

[image: graph of $y=\dfrac{x^3}{3}+x^2-8x+10$]